# Missing number and illegal unit of measure in list of tables

Tags: errors, lists, templates, xepersian

I want to use the template sharifthesis given in this [link](https://github.com/momeni/sharif-thesis/blob/master/sharifthesis.cls) to create my thesis (Please see the minimal example). But it gives 2 errors:

```
line 1: Missing number, treated as zero. ...ons and labels\relax }}{1}{table.caption.2}
line 1: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...ons and labels\relax }}{1}{table.caption.2}
```

and the file `test.lot`, to which the error points, is as follows:

```
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {\relax 0.1}{\ignorespaces Table to test captions and labels\relax }}{1}{table.caption.2}%
```

The minimal example is here:

```
\documentclass[PhDThesis,twoside]{sharifthesis2}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            \hline
            Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ 
            \hline\hline
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
            2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table to test captions and labels}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I don't know where is the source of the problem. I used this template 2 years ago on another computer and everything was fine.

**EDIT**:
I've also provided a minimal version of the template that reproduces the error (`sharifthesis2.cls`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sharifthesis2}[2017/08/03 Sharif Thesis v1.5.1]

\DeclareOption{PhDThesis}{\def\@fordegree{test}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=.7cm,headsepline,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1]{Arial}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[PhDThesis,twoside]{sharifthesis2}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\scr@dte@tocline
  {\@nameuse{scr@tso@#1@pagenumberbox}}
  {\expandafter\let\expandafter\scr@dte@pagenumberwidth
   \csname scr@tso@#1@pagenumberwidth\endcsname
   \@nameuse{scr@tso@#1@pagenumberbox}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            \hline
            Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ 
            \hline\hline
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
            2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table to test captions and labels}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is a known problem of `bidi` package, and has already been reported at https://github.com/persiantex/bidi/issues/7. I also replied that issue.